# Mathematica and analytical solution not matching

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, mathematical-optimization

I have the function $$f(r,t)=r^{2n}-2 r^n\cos nt+1$$ where $n $ is an integer. I want to find the maximum value of $f$ over $(r,t) \in  [0,1] \times[0,2 \pi]$.  As usual  in order to find the critical points, we equate to  zero the two derivatives  as follows:
$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial r}=0 \implies 2nr^{2n}-2n r^n \cos nt=  0  
$$ and
$$ \frac{\partial f}{\partial t}=0  \implies 2r^n \sin nt=0.$$This gives us $$ r^n(r^n-\cos nt)=0   \,\text{and}\, r^n \sin nt=0.$$ I  think this should give us $r=1$ and $t=\frac{m \pi}{n}$. For $n=20$, Mathematica and the solution thus obtained do not match.

```
n = 20; 
f[r_, t_] = r^(2 n) - 2 r^n Cos[n*t] + 1; 
Maximize[{f[r, t], 0 <= r <= 1, 0 <= t <= 2 Pi}, {r, t}]
```

Can somebody kindly  point out why that is so? How should I choose $m$?

Comment: this is the Mathematica code that somebody provided on this site for the same in a previous question.......n = 20; f[r_, t_] = r^(2 n) - 2 r^n Cos[n*t] + 1; Maximize[{f[r, t], 0 <= r <= 1, 0 <= t <= 2 Pi}, {r, t}]

Comment: n = 20; f[r_, t_] = r^(2 n) - 2 r^n Cos[n*t] + 1; Maximize[{f[r, t], 0 <= r <= 1, 0 <= t <= 2 Pi}, {r, t}]

Comment: it gives $t=  3 \pi/20$ and the anlytical solution gives $t=\pi/20$ and the maximum value is given to be 4

Comment: Edit to place the code into the post, not as a comment.

Answer (score 2):

If you make a plot of your function:

```
n = 20;
f[r_, t_] = r^(2 n) - 2 r^n Cos[n*t] + 1;
Plot[f[1, t], {t, 0, 2 Pi}]
```

[image]

you see that there are many maxima. Your question has no unique answer. To get a unique answer you may restrict the range of t to e.g. {0,Pi/10}:

```
n = 20; f[r_, t_] = 
 r^(2 n) - 2 r^n Cos[n*t] + 1; System`Maximize[{f[r, t], 0 <= r <= 1, 
  0 <= t <= Pi/10}, {r, t}]
```

[image]

Comment: the plot has to be a surface and not a curve

Comment: For simplicity i set r=1. The problem is the same for any value of R

Answer (score 2):

Amplifying on [`answer`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/262677/9362) by Daniel Huber

```
Clear["Global`*"]

n = 20;
f[r_, t_] = r^(2 n) - 2 r^n Cos[n*t] + 1;

Plot3D[f[r, t], {t, 0, 2 Pi}, {r, 0, 1},
 PlotRange -> All,
 PlotPoints -> 75,
 MaxRecursion -> 3,
 AxesLabel -> (Style[#, 14] & /@ {t, r, f})]
```

[image]

For a given `r` the maxima are at

```
argmaxt = Assuming[0 < r <= 1,
  Solve[{D[f[r, t], t] == 0, D[f[r, t], {t, 2}] < 0,
     0 <= r <= 1, 0 <= t <= 2 Pi}, t] // Simplify]

(* {{t -> π/20}, {t -> (3 π)/20}, {t -> π/4}, {t -> (7 π)/
   20}, {t -> (9 π)/20}, {t -> (11 π)/20}, {t -> (13 π)/
   20}, {t -> (3 π)/4}, {t -> (17 π)/20}, {t -> (19 π)/
   20}, {t -> (21 π)/20}, {t -> (23 π)/20}, {t -> (5 π)/
   4}, {t -> (27 π)/20}, {t -> (29 π)/20}, {t -> (31 π)/
   20}, {t -> (33 π)/20}, {t -> (7 π)/4}, {t -> (37 π)/
   20}, {t -> (39 π)/20}} *)
```

For a given `r` all the maxima are equal and given by

```
maxr = f[r, t] /. argmaxt // Union

(* {1 + 2 r^20 + r^40} *)

Maximize[{maxr[[1]], 0 < r <= 1}, r]

(* {4, {r -> 1}} *)
```